How to get a Hubspot cookies in Angular 17?
I want to ask about the Hubspot cookies. I have a website with Hubspot integration, and there is a login email in cookies when I logged in. How can I check that email in cookies like in an example above? 'ngx-cookies-service' doesn't see the Hubspot fields.
'document.cookie' also doesn't have the Hubspot cookie.
Thanks in advance!
I need to check the visitor email here for redirect to login or sign-up page on button click:
goToConsole(url: string) {
    const visitor = this.#apiService.hubspotVisitor();
    if (visitor) {
        window.open(url + '/auth/login', '_self');
    } else {
            window.open(url + '/auth/registration', '_self');
        }
    }

this example is not working:
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';

constructor(private cookieService: CookieService) {}

this.visitorEmail = this.cookieService.get('hs_login_email');


